# How to change input blue activate border to red

Tags: javascript, html, forms, bootstrap-4

I have a form with an email field:

```html
<input id="email-input" type="email" class="form-control" required>
```

This code provides a front validation (based on email regex pattern) but I am also looking for a server check to make sure emails are unique.

I have build a ajax request to ask backend weather email exists or not. This part works well.

Is there a simple way to turn bootstrap blue activation border to red?

[image]

**What I have tried:**

On backend validation error, add a bootstrap border:

```html
<span class="border border-danger">
    <input id="email-input" type="email" class="form-control" required>
</span>
```

And the result is quite ugly.

Comment: Take a look @ https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#validation

Comment: Thanks @Simon, even better there is a section for server side validation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#server-side. I am going to delete my post.

Answer (score 0):

include this css and add **"error-field"** class to input when user added invalid email else remove class **"error-field"**

- If you want show red border when user not focused the input than remove **:focus** from css code

```css
input#email-input.error-field:focus {
   border-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
  email = email.toString().toLowerCase();
  const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}

document.getElementById('email').oninput = function() {
  if (this.value.length == 0) {
    this.classList.remove("email");
    this.classList.remove("err");
    return;
  }
  let status = validateEmail(this.value);
  if (status) {
    this.classList.add("email");
    this.classList.remove("err");
  } else {
    this.classList.remove("email");
    this.classList.add("err");
  }
};
```

```css
.err {
  border-color: red;
}

.email {
  border-color: green;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input id='email' type='email' required/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap

```
   .form-control:focus
{
       box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
       border: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```